# jenkins naginator plugin in dsl

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

Has anyone use the naginator plugin in job-dsl ?

we can simply configure the job with below block:

```
job('example') {
    publishers {
        retryBuild {
            rerunIfUnstable()
            retryLimit(3)
            progressiveDelay(60, 600)
        }
    }
}
```

but how to configure the option below , should use configure block?:

Only rerun build if regular expression is found in output

[Screenshot about the option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYErR.png)

Comment: I don't see any of these steps (`job`, `publishers` etc.) listed when I went to "Pipeline Syntax". I don't see them in the documentation either: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/. What plugin is providing these steps for you?

Comment: I guess you need to install job-dsl plugin. I assumed that you are referring to pipeline DSL.

Comment: Could you please explain how other plugin will affect the "Only rerun build if regular expression is found in output" option?

Comment: @FrankXie Did you make some progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

Same need, I managed to configure 'regexpForRerun' with a configure block like this :

```
configure { project ->
    project / publishers << 'com.chikli.hudson.plugin.naginator.NaginatorPublisher' {
        regexpForRerun('.*Retry later.*')
        rerunIfUnstable(true)
        rerunMatrixPart(false)
        checkRegexp(true)
        maxSchedule(3)
        delay(class: 'com.chikli.hudson.plugin.naginator.FixedDelay') {
            delay 3600
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this can help other people.